# Draw $-dU(x)/dx$ for $U(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

It's been a little while since I've done any problems like this, but I just wanted to make sure I'm on the right track.

[image: My Work]

Updated attempt:

[image: Attempt 2]

Comment: It seems like $dU/dx \to 0$ for large $x$, but your sketch does not have that. Also it seems like $U$ goes from being convex to concave (i.e. $U''=0$ and $U'$ has a local max) around $x=2$

Comment: @Winther can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @Winther got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your $u$ has a horizontal asymptote. so you you know the derivative should have a horizontal asymptote too. you derivative will have a positive local max and then decrease and approach zero. your derivative should look a little bit like the reflection on the $x$-axis of $u.$

Comment: So my line shouldn't go above $x=2$ once it becomes positive on my $dU/dx$ graph?

Comment: the derivative reaches maximum  just before 2(inflection point). you can estimate what the the slope at that point. it looks about 3-4.

Comment: I updated my question with a second attempt, mind giving it a look?

Comment: looks much better. little work to do. do you know what is mean by the graph is concave up(like a cup)/down(hat). if the graph of $\frac{du}{dx}$ is positive and asymptoting to zero then it must do as a concave up. on $(0, 2), du/dx$ looks like a hat and on $(2, \infty)$ it looks like a cup.